# fetch data form two table

Tags: php, database, codeigniter

the first table :
[question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/akLnK.png)
the second table :
[answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mol4B.png)
i use them for my exam.
for each question i have 3 answer. my problem is to fetch them together and after fetch i want have array like this :

```
[0]=>array(8) 
{
    ["question"]=>  string(13) "question test"
    ["name_id"]=>   string(1) "1"
    ["answer"]=>    string(1) "1"
    ["points"]=>    string(1) "1"
    ["answer"]=>    string(1) "2"
    ["points"]=>    string(1) "2"
    ["answer"]=>    string(1) "3"
    ["points"]=>    string(1) "3"
}
```

but because the key answer and points are same i get this after fetch :

```
[0]=>array(4) 
{
    ["question"]=>  string(13) "question test"
    ["name_id"]=>   string(1) "1"
    ["answer"]=>    string(1) "1"
    ["points"]=>    string(1) "1"
}   
[1]=>array(4) 
{
    ["question"]=>  string(13) "question test"
    ["name_id"]=>   string(1) "1"
    ["answer"]=>    string(1) "2"
    ["points"]=>    string(1) "2"
}   
[2]=>array(4) 
{
    ["question"]=>  string(13) "question test"
    ["name_id"]=>   string(1) "1"
    ["answer"]=>    string(1) "3"
    ["points"]=>    string(1) "3"
}
```

the query i write is :

```
select question , name_id , answer, points from question , answer where question.id_question = answer.id_aquestion
```

is there any solution fetch them in one array not 3 array ?
(the framework i use codeigniter)

Comment: can your  model function ?

Comment: i edited your question because now you can see that your desired result is impossible with such a structure - you have to split your items from the `answer` table in to separate items and add them to a given array in your question item - the second thing is - you should post what you've tried so far, almost no one is willing to help you here - because this is not a code writing service (although i assume you already know that...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have the same key name with different values first of all.
It will just overwrite the value...
This is what you could do:

```
foreach ($results as $rowKey => $rowVal) {
    $processedResults[0] = [
        "question" => $rowVal["question"],
        "name_id" => $rowVal["name_id"],
        "answer" . $rowKey => $rowVal["answer"],
        "points" . $rowKey => $rowVal["points"]
    ];
}
```

This way you'll get

```
[0]=>array(x) 
{
    ["question"] => string(13) "question test"
    ["name_id"] => string(1) "1"
    ["answer0"] => string(1) "1"
    ["points0"] => string(1) "1"
    ["answer1"] => string(1) "2"
    ["points1"] => string(1) "2"
    ["answer2"] => string(1) "3"
    ["points2"] => string(1) "3"
    ....
    ["answerx"] => string(1) "x"
    ["pointsx"] => string(1) "x"
}
```